# If I never once reference System.IO in my program, why does my user get an error?

Tags: .net, vb.net, runtime-error

I have a program which doesn't once reference System.I0, coded in vb.net, yet for some reason my user got this:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: advancedclipboard.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4a903bf5
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualBasic
  Problem Signature 05: 8.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4889f422
  Problem Signature 07: 6e
  Problem Signature 08: 8
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.0.6000.2.0.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
```

in the crash report from once the program started.

I am using the Krypton Toolkit from componentfactory.com and an obfuscator from http://ntcore.com/phoenix.php.

The user was running Vista, and I have no idea if they have the .net framework installed.

Any one of these things could have happened, I think:

- The lack of a .net framework installed crashed it
- The Krypton Toolkit needed me to package a .dll with it (not likely)
- The obfuscator obfuscated my code and broke it

Which of these is the most likely to have broken my program?

Comment: I'd say that Krypton definitely uses System.IO.

Comment: I think I isolated the issue, and yeah, it was probably Krypton. What .dlls do I need to package with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include **ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll** with your app.

Comment: Where on the users computer should it be located?

Comment: In the same folder as the app. It might work if the .dll is in a folder in your system path.

Answer (score 3):

If this log came from the user machine, it has the .Net Framework installed. Otherwise a FileNotFoundException wouldn't be thrown.
It may be the case that the third party component is trying to find a file or it may be the case your code is trying indirectly through the .Net Framework's code. Serialization can do this.

Comment: It may be the case they have a different version of the Framework than the one you compiled your application against.

Comment: How can I check which one they have with my script?

Answer (score 2):

The crash is stating that it couldn't find the advancedclipboard.exe.

Do you know what in your code or the code you are using like the toolkit that requires this file?

EDIT:

Forget my duh moment please....  The comments say it all. :)

Comment: Nope. It's the one who generated the crash. advancedclipboard or one of it's dependencies is trying to find another file.

Comment: They were running advancedclipboard.exe, not anything else.

Nothing requires it, it *is* the program.

Comment: Lol ;) I hate it when that happens to me!